# Is there a simple way to tell alembic to migrate to a specific revision?

Tags: database, database-migration, alembic

Alembic has commands to upgrade and downgrade to a specific revision, e.g. on the command line:

```
alembic upgrade <target-revision>
```

And

```
alembic downgrade <target-revision>
```

Is there a simple way to migrate to a specific revision if you don't know whether it's an upgrade or a downgrade? i.e.

```
alembic migrate <target-revision>
```

I can work out the direction by looking at the history, current and target revisions, but this feels like fighting the library. Am I missing something or is there a reason why this isn't provided out of the box?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It turns out there's a very simple, pragmatic solution to this:

```
alembic upgrade <target-revision> || alembic downgrade <target-revision>
```

Comment: This is fine but there might be times you don't want migrations to run past a certain point, like if you're trying to resolve conflicts or fix something in a migration that's being developed.